# Uncaught Error: THREE.Quaternion: .setFromEuler() now expects a Euler rotation rather than a Vector3 and order

Tags: javascript, iframe, 3d, three.js

I am using ThreeJS/WebGL to demonstrate a rotating planet inside of an iframe. It is working fine except for a warning and an issue:

```
Warning: THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture is not power of two. Texture.minFilter should be set to THREE.NearestFilter or THREE.LinearFilter. 

Issue: Uncaught Error: THREE.Quaternion: .setFromEuler() now expects a Euler rotation rather than a Vector3 and order.
```

I have included the following assets into the body of the iframe:

```
<div id="webgl"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bubblin/The-Solar-System/master/jupiter/js/detector.js"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bubblin/The-Solar-System/master/jupiter/js/trackBallControls.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bubblin/The-Solar-System/master/jupiter/js/xRingGeometry.js"> </script>
```

As you can see I'm using trackBallControls.js to rotate the sphere based on user input/touch and I have overridden a `RingGeometry` method to layer the ring_image along the circumference instead of emanating it radially.

Here's my complete code to simulate Jupiter, for example:

```
(function() {
  var webglEl = document.getElementById('webgl');
  if (!Detector.webgl) {
    Detector.addGetWebGLMessage(webglEl);
    return;
  }
  THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
  var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;
  var radius = 0.45,
    segments = 32,
    rotation = 5;
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.01, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 3;
  camera.position.y = 1;
  camera.position.x = -1;
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x553333));
  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, .5);
  light.position.set(5, 3, 5);
  scene.add(light);
  var sphere = createSphere(radius, segments);
  sphere.rotation.y = rotation;
  scene.add(sphere);
  var rings = createRings(radius, segments);
  rings.rotation.y = rotation;
  scene.add(rings);
  var stars = createStars(90, 64);
  scene.add(stars);
  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
  webglEl.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  render();

  function render() {
    controls.update();
    sphere.rotation.y += 0.08;
    rings.rotation.y += 0.05;
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  function createSphere(radius, segments) {
    return new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://cdn.rawgit.com/marvindanig/Images/master/jupiter/jupitermap.jpg'),
      bumpScale: 0.05,
      specular: new THREE.Color('#190909')
    }));
  }

  function createRings(radius, segments) {
    return new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.XRingGeometry(1.3 * radius, 1.6 * radius, 2 * segments, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://cdn.rawgit.com/bubblin/The-Solar-System/master/jupiter/images/rings.png'),
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 0.2,
      specular: new THREE.Color('#495909')
    }));
  }

  function createStars(radius, segments) {
    return new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://cdn.rawgit.com/marvindanig/Images/master/galaxy_starfield.png'),
      side: THREE.BackSide
    }));
  }
}());
```

It works (See the output [here](https://bubbl.in/book/the-solar-system-by-marvin-danig/44)), but I get those warnings and an error. The errors and warnings eventually build up, and my app crashes on the iPad/iPhone.

Please help, I am new to ThreeJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding:

```
Warning: THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture is not power of two. Texture.minFilter should be set to THREE.NearestFilter or THREE.LinearFilter.
```

In computer graphics, [textures that are powers of two can be processed faster](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent) than those that are not which is why you get the warning. I suggest you resize both the sphere texture and rings texture to square powers of two using your favourite image editor. Alternatively, you can set the `minFilter` as suggested by the warning:

```
  function createSphere(radius, segments) {
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://cdn.rawgit.com/marvindanig/Images/master/jupiter/jupitermap.jpg');
    texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    return new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      bumpScale: 0.05,
      specular: new THREE.Color('#190909')
    }));
  }
```

As for the second error, I'm not seeing it on Chrome 42 but it is caused because one of your scripts (that likely isn't shown here as I could not find the problem in any of them) uses `Quaternion.setFromEuler` like this:

```
 quat.setFromEuler(new THREE.Vector3(pitch, yaw, roll));
```

when it should it be using like this:

```
 quat.setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(pitch, yaw, roll));
```

Do a quick **CTRL + F** in your code and you'll find the faulty script.

Comment: Those are all the scripts I have inside my iframe. Apparently the error comes in editing-mode only, especially when the iframe is re-rendered upon page turn. What I have linked up here is the reading mode, and yes I too am not getting that error on Chrome anymore. Let me circle back with that question separately, in case I'm unable to fix it with suggestions here. Thanks for the tip/gyan on Textures b.t.w!